# Changing the initial load screen at different conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 views as shown in the following diagram. First View is a `ViewController` and the 2nd is a `TableViewController`.

After the user installs and runs the app for the first time he/she will see View number (1) (as shown in the image). Thereafter when the user opens the application for the 2nd time he/she is suppose to see the second (2) `viewcontroller`.

How am i to program this ?

[image]

NB: For example in Viber the user will first see the Enter the phone number view controller, and once the user successfully logins he'll directly see the all contacts view. I am looking to implement the same functionality. Can someone tell me how this is done ?

Solution i came across is when the user successffully logins, i set a NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:loginSuccess forKey:@"yes"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Thereafter i check if this is set in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Is this the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSUserDefaults` is a great way to keep track of which view to show.  To actually *show* the correct view you make the `UITableViewController` the root view controller for your app.  Then in its `viewDidLoad` you check the value you stored in `NSUserDefaults`.  If you need to display the one-time-only controller then you can simply use `presentViewController:vc animated: NO`.  This will make it appear to the user that they started at the one-time-only controller, but for the rest of time you will have the "normal" flow work as expected.

Comment: What you mean is to make the TableViewController as my initial View ? And then through a condition to check if `NSUserdefaults`  has been set and navigate accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the second call by using NSUserDefaults. Upon start check for a value for any key. When that is null then it is the first time after installation, that the app is executed. After that store something with the very key.

You can do the check in your application delegate (in application didLodWithOptions) and then show either this or that.

Or you perform the check in viewDidLoad in your tableview controller. You can simply push to the other view (or display it modally). This is quite convenient when you want the user to return to the tableview as soon as his introduction is over. Then simply discard the other view ontop of the tableview.